# Помощь в теге progress и в PHP

Tags: php, html, css, html5

возникла проблема с PHP и с тегом progress. Я хочу, чтобы линия с значением была серого цвета. Значение $Player->get_exp(): 8113

PHP:

```
<?php                               
if ($Player->get_exp() <= 50000) {
     echo '<progress value="$Player->get_exp()" max="50000"></progress>';
}
?>
```

CSS:

```
progress {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Вот как выводится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что у Вас ошибка в `value="$Player->get_exp()"` и надо написать

```
echo '<progress value="'.$Player->get_exp().'" max="50000"></progress>';
```